# Handling Non-Specified & Non-Empty Getch() (C program)

Tags: c, while-loop, ncurses, getch

I'm trying to handle when a user inputs something that is not specifically taken note of in the code. I'm using getch() and when a user inputs '1' there is a conditional that reacts to it; however, what I want to achieve is that if a user enters anything else another conditional will react to it. I would think this means to check if getch() != EOF and if getch() != '1' but I'm not getting the results I thought I would... sometimes the conditional hits, sometimes it doesn't. My code is below (remember to compile with -lncurses):

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
    initscr();

    // makes user input immediately available
    cbreak();

    // makes getch() not echo user unput
    noecho();

    // if user input is excessive use the scroll to show it
    scrollok(stdscr, TRUE);

    // turns getch() into a non-blocking call
    nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);

    // loop forever
    while (true) {

        // if the user enters '1' its a hit
        if (getch() == '1') {
            printw("WHACK!\n");
        }

        // anything else is a miss
        if ( (getch() != '1') && (getch() != EOF) ){
            printw("SWING AND A MISS!\n");
        }

        // sleep for 300 milliseconds
        napms(300);
        printw(".\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to use the `else` keyword, but it's not very clear what you want.

Comment: `if (getch() == '1') { printw("WHACK!\n"); } else { printw("SWING AND A MISS"); }` perhaps?

Comment: @Evert unfortunately that will just print swing and a miss continuously because of the loop, I need to be a bit more specific than that.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I want for just (".\n") to be printed with nothing is entered, "Whack!" to be printed when a '1' is entered, and "Swing and a miss!" to be printed when anything else is entered

Comment: @laroy please don't put clarifications in comments but edit your question and put them _there_.

Comment: `getch` returns `ERR` when no input has been entered. You should test for this. Read [this](https://linux.die.net/man/3/timeout) for more details.

Comment: You should probably assign the result of `getch()` to a variable and test that, rather than calling `getch()` several times... you only want to read one character on each loop pass, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is wrong.

You probably want this:

```
while (true) {
    int c = getch();

    if (c == ERR) {                      // no key pressed
        printw(".\n");
    }
    else if (c == '1') {                 // if the user enters '1' its a hit
        printw("WHACK!\n");
    }
    else {                               // anything else is a miss       
        printw("SWING AND A MISS!\n");
    }

    // sleep for 300 milliseconds
    napms(300);
}
```

Disclaimer: this is untested code.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Is there any need  to flush stdin or clear getch in any way?

Comment: @laroy I don't know, probably not. That's likely another question.

Comment: @laroy - I believe `fflush(stdin)` invokes undefined behavior